# Azure Search indexer datasource SQL query size limit of 8192 characters

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cognitive-search

We're using Azure Search and DocumentDB on Azure.  Search is populated by an indexer that references the target index and the datasource.  The datasource is bound to a DocumentDb instance.

In binding the Indexer to DocumentDB, we have written a simple SQL query that retrieves the docs and flattens the hierarchy.  The problem is, in order to flatten the hierarchy you have to use a lot of SQL aliases which makes the SQL query very verbose.

Recently the number of fields has grown a lot, and now whenever the indexer is run, we get the error:

> The SQL query text exceeded the maximum limit of 8192

It appears that we have reached the limit with this approach.  8192 chars is not very much at all, especially given that we have to flatten hierarchy with loads of aliases.

You can easily reproduce this problem by going into Query Explorer in the Azure Portal and entering a simple SQL query and giving a column a really long alias that takes the query length of the 8192 limit and you'll see the issue.

Does anyone know of a work-around?  It looks like we're probably going to have to avoid the Search Indexer functionality and go for the manual approach of simply using the Search API to create/update/delete documents in the index.

We have also thought about trying to reduce the size/verbosity of our aliases, but this will break a lot of existing code.

thanks for your help

Comment: Rather than searching via documentdb queries, have you thought about using azure search instead?  https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/documentdb-search-indexer/

Comment: I work on Azure Search. Could you email me your documentdb account name and your query to eugenesh at the usual Microsoft domain? Thanks!

Comment: @Will yep, we are using Azure Search.  The problem is that the Azure Search Indexer uses a Datasource that contains a SQL query to get the data out of DocumentDB; this query has become too large and returns an error when indexing.

Comment: @EugeneShvets-MSFT Thanks for the message; I'll email you now.

Comment: Hey, guys, if you work a solution out for this, please post an answer with details, I'd be interested in hearing it (have a project which might leverage both).

Comment: Have you considered using a stored procedure instead?